# Not able to pass a string value in javascript function

Tags: javascript, fusioncharts

```
for(int i = 0; i < ob.length; i++) {
  logger.logDebug(this.getClass(),"ob value check- "+ob[i].toString());
  String val=ob[i].toString();
  strXML1.append("<graph caption='City Wise Total Properties' xAxisName='City' yAxisName='Count' decimalPrecision='0' formatNumberScale='0'>")
         .append("<set name='")
         .append(ob[i].toString())
         .append("'  value='" + ob1[i].toString())
         .append( "'color='A186BE' link='javascript:drillDownReport1(2,"+val+")' />")
         .append("</graph>");
  }
```

I am not getting the value of `val` using the following JavaScript function:

```
function drillDownReport1(reportnumber,val) {
    alert("val"+val);
}
```

Any help appreciated!

Comment: What are you getting in the alert?

Comment: please help for what? what you need to do and what is the question here?

Comment: You are asking or telling something? Completely unable to get you :( You can't just pick a portion of Code and put in a question like this. Indeed, you need to elaborate it a bit :)

Comment: @SubirKumarSao I am not getting any alert...It throws error value of val is undefined..........

Comment: @ChamikaSandamal I need to get value of val in javascript function..But not able to get the value of val.Ob[i].tostring refers to cityname....

Comment: Are you using FusionCharts Free or FusionCharts v3? If v3, then JavaScript charts, Flash Charts or both?

Comment: @ShamasisBhattacharya I am using Fusion charts free.....Do you have any solution for this...??

Answer (score 2):

It's because the javascript generated is, if `val` = "toto"

```
javascript:drillDownReport1(2,toto)' />")
```

and not

```
javascript:drillDownReport1(2,"toto")' />")
```

So you need to escape with quote your string. Like that:

```
.append( "'color='A186BE' link='javascript:drillDownReport1(2,\""+val+"')' />")
```

Comment: I have used this already...By using above way I am not able to view the fusionchart graph to whom i want to pass above stringXMl

Answer (score 1):

Use

```
var val=ob[i].toString();
```

instead of

```
String val=ob[i].toString();
```

?

Cause, you know, this is JavaScript.

Comment: This is JSP generating javascript.

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is the way you are putting the value of `val` in your function

Since `val` is a string, you need to put that in quotes.

```
strXML1.append("<graph caption='City Wise Total Properties' xAxisName='City' yAxisName='Count' decimalPrecision='0' formatNumberScale='0'>")
        .append("<set name='")
        .append(ob[i].toString())
        .append("'  value='" + ob1[i].toString())
        .append( "'color='A186BE' link='javascript:drillDownReport1(2,\""+val+"\")' />")
        .append("</graph>");
```